# System is not defined issue: Angular 6 and Cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova, systemjs

I am trying to run my angular migration app in android/ios using cordova.I am using systemjs loader for my angular app.When I run the cordova run android command,app throws the following errors as shown in the image.

[image: console error]

I tried changing the base href  as  and also referred the following link,

Could anyone help me with this error? As I am stuck here and could not proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred as the node_modules was outside www folder and android uses www folder for apk generation.